# Newton's forward-difference formula question?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

Use Newton's forward-difference formula to construct interpolating polynomials of degree 
two, and three for the following data. Approximate the 
specified value using each of the polynomials.

I have to approximate $f(8.4)$ if 
$f(8.1)=16.94410$ , $f(8.3)=17.56492$ , $f(8.6)=18.50515$ , $f(8.7)=18.82091$

I know that the formula in this case is 
 $$P(x_{0}+hs)=f_{0}+s\Delta
    f_{0}+\frac{s(s-1)}{2!}\Delta^{2}f_{0}+\cdots+\frac{s(s-1)(s-2)...(s-n+1)}{n!}\Delta^{n}f_{0}$$
     where $$s=\frac{(x-x_{0})}{h}; \qquad f_0=f(x_0); \qquad\Delta^k f_i=\sum_{j=0}^k{(-1)^j \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}f_{i+k-j}}$$

Problem is,what is **h** in this case,since $x_{1}-x_{0}=0.2$ , $x_{2}-x_{1}=0.3$ and $x_{3}-x_{2}=0.1$ ?

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2337170/173147

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, Newton's forward Interpolation formula can not be used.

This formula can be used only for equi-spaced arguments.

For non-equispaced arguments apply Lagrange's interpolation formula.