# Intuition for the coefficients in divided difference polynomials

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

I read the example on the [Wikipedia page on divided differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divided_differences#Example),
but I don't understand why we do this "slope" thing  $\frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0}$
between every known point, and why does it really solve our interpolation problem?

Because at this point I'm just plugging in the values without really understanding what's happening under the hood.

How do you explain this to yourself ? (maybe an image or any other intuitive approach)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

we want a polynomial function of lowest degree that goes through $(x_0,y_0)$

$y = y_0$

Now we want it to go through $(x_1,y_1)$, too.

$y = y_0 + \phi_1(x-x_0)$

For any $\phi$ this line will still go through $(x_0,y_0)$ and we will need to find $\phi_1.$

$y = y_0 + \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}(x-x_0)$

Now we want it to go through $(x_2,y_2)$, too.

$y = y_0 + \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}(x-x_0) + \phi_2(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$
$y(x_2) = y_2 = y_0 + \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}(x_2-x_0) + \phi_2(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)\\
\phi_2 = \frac {(y_2-y_0)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)} - \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}\\
\phi_2 = \frac {\frac {(y_2-y_0)}{(x_2-x_0)} - \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}}{(x_2-x_1)}$

etc.

Comment: thanks a lot ! now I even feel bad for asking ...

Comment: I don't think that this stuck the first few times I saw it.  It was actually thinking about it the way I describe it here, that it finally stuck.

Comment: your answer should be added to wiki :)

Comment: and by shaping it a little bit we should come to $\phi_2 = \frac {\frac {(y_2-y_1)}{(x_2-x_1)} - \frac {(y_1-y_0)}{(x_1-x_0)}}{(x_2-x_0)}$ right ?

Answer (score 0):

another way to think about it is that the second divided difference is a way of measuring how much the slope has changed. the problem is that unlike with derivatives, in discrete cases you need 2 points to define a slope and you are kind of forced to chose which one to use. Picking the extremities seem like a good option because it has the property that the divided difference doesn't get affected by permutation.

This is the intuition I had when I learned calculus and tried to prove the polynomial interpolation theorem. too many linear equations and gave up...
given n points, you have n-1 slopes, n-2 mesure of curvature, etc and I hoped that that there were only a single polynomial associated with them.

This method is much more useful in the constant gap between inputs special case. Then it works pretty much exactly like a taylor series but instead of exponentials, you get a falling order factorial in the form(x-n)(x-n-1)...(x-m).
and given n points in that case, you can find the n-1th difference and guess the interpolation polynomial from there.